# Can I use a boost converter as a batteries replacement?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I have two 12V car batteries in series that control a stepper motor system, my question is if I can raise the voltage to 48V using a step-up converter (with the necessary power obviously) to increase the speed of the system.

Comment: Yes you can. Why not?

Comment: "to increase the speed of the system." Is your stepper motor rated for 48V?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the motor makes no sense, the stepper voltage is controlled by the stepper driver, and yes, the stepper driver is rated for 48V

Comment: The motor ratings do "make sense" -- if you drive them too hard you can damage them, and just because a (presumably) generic stepper controller is rated at 48V doesn't mean it'll protect the motors unless it's properly set up to do so, according to the needs of the motors.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your system....   The stepper motors 'speed' is likely controlled by a digital computer.  It won't run faster because you increase the voltage.   The CPU is gonna do what the CPU is gonna do.   What will happen is the motor will get more TORQUE.  It may move from position to position faster, but it'll dwell at each new position the same amount of time as it would have prior.

Comment: The stepper motor driver must be matched to the stepper motor.  Which means the stepper motor must be rated for 48V.

Answer (score 2):

Stepper speed isn't entirely dependent on voltage. I would advise against doing what you're thinking of. You're likely going to fry your controller and/or your motors. Check the data sheet/product information of your motor and product information on your controller to see what maximum speeds there are.

Like your comments have said, yes you can get 48 V out of two 12 V batteries using a boost converter, but your boost converter may not be putting out a pure DC signal, and your controller and motors may not be rated for it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can drive motors off of a boost converter.  You need to take care when doing so -- motor power requirements are "bursty", and motors are often rated for the average power they consume, not the maximum.

You need to calculate, or measure, the short-term peak current that your stepper drivers will consume, and use a boost converter that will be able to supply that current without shutting down.

Typically, in a product design environment where the power consumption is dominated by motors, it's cheaper to select motors that match the power rail rather than changing the voltage of the power rail to fit the motors.  If that's what you're doing, you may want to see if there's a different wind available for your motors that generates the same torque at half the voltage and twice the current.  If you're doing a one-off, a step-up may make perfect sense, though.